# Procedure for using Previous Versions to restore a folder that was accidentally deleted, without restoring everything around it

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, shadow-copy

We have ShadowCopy enabled so that files can be reverted to previous versions.  Sometimes, a folder is accidentally deleted.  The known fix is to restore the containing folder, but that restores everything in the containing folder, even known good work.  Is there a better way to use Previous Versions?  Windows 7, Windows Server 2008.

Example : \SERVER\share\1\A and \SERVER\share\1\B exist.  A is accidentally deleted.  I can restore folder 1 to get A back, but I lose work on B in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow copy should let you "browse" the folders that were changed or deleted and you can then just copy the folder or files to the specific location.